# permutation & combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many odd three digit numbers are there when tens digit is greater than units digit and hundreds digit is greater than tens digit?

- $225$
- $ 45$
- $ 50$
- $230$

---

My attempt:

The units digit can be $1$ or $3$ or $5$ so $3$ ways ($9$ cannot be taken)

units digit when = 1       _ _ _1  ten's digit = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8

in this if ten's digit = 2  hundred's digit =  3,4,5,6,7,8,9..  -- 7 ways

in this if ten's digit = 3  hundred's digit =  4,5,6,7,8,9...     6 ways

so on upto ten's = 8 hundreds = 9 --1 way  i.e, nothing but  sum of first 7 terms  i.e, 28
similarly for unit's= 3  ten's digit = 4,5,6,7,8     hundred's digit =  ,5,6,7,8,9..  -- 5 ways

so on upto ten's = 8 hundreds = 9 --1 way  i.e, nothing but  sum of first 5 terms  i.e, 15

similarly for unit's = 5 the ways can be  6  total 28+15+6 = 49
one number remained is 987 with this it is 50 ways.

calculating this take more time can anyone reduce this or is there any formula for this type of ques...

Comment: What are your thoughts? a and d are very close together, but very far apart from b and c. Why do you think this is?

Comment: Please note that copy-pasting of homework problems is frowned upon here. You should *at least* tell us what you tried to solve it.

Comment: i had got answer 50 through my calculaton but it is too time taking and i cant conform it whether it is correct or not

Comment: just try with --- 3 digit where last can be filled by 1 or 3 or 5 only and so on

Comment: $987$ fulfils all conditions, but its unit digit is none of $1$, $3$ or $5$.

Answer (score 4):

Each number must end with $1$ or $3$ or $5$ or $7$:

- In order to generate numbers that end with $1$, choose $2$ digits from $[2\dots9]$
- In order to generate numbers that end with $3$, choose $2$ digits from $[4\dots9]$
- In order to generate numbers that end with $5$, choose $2$ digits from $[6\dots9]$
- In order to generate numbers that end with $7$, choose $2$ digits from $[8\dots9]$

So the total amount of numbers is $\binom82+\binom62+\binom42+\binom22=28+15+6+1=50$.

Answer (score 2):

How many solutions does $a>b>c$ have for $a,b,c\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$?

Hint: for a given choice of $b$, how many choices do you have for $a$ and $c$? And how could it possibly be related to [this strange sum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20floor%28b%2F2%29*%289-b%29)?

Answer (score 1):

For a number to be odd, it must end with $1$ or $3$ or $5$ or $7$

**Ending with 1:** Let us fix $1$ at one's place now we have to fill ten's and hundred's place such that tens digit is greater than units digit and hundreds digit is greater than tens digit.

Placing $2$ at ten's place leaves us with $[3,4,5,6,7,8,9]$ i.e, $7$ choices.
Placing $3$ at ten's place leaves us with $[4,5,6,7,8,9]$ -- $6$ choices.
Placing $4$ at ten's places leaves us with $[5,6,7,8,9]$ i.e, 5 choices... so on.

No. of odd three digit numbers with 1 at one's place = $7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 28$

**Ending with 3:** Fixing $3$ at one's place and filling ten's place with $4,5,6,7,8,9$ respectively leaves us with $5,4,3,2,1$ ways that sum up to $15$

**Ending with 5:** Fixing $5$ at one's place and filling ten's place with $6,7,8,9$ respectively leaves us with $3,2,1,0$ ways that sum up to $6$

**Ending with 7:** Fixing $7$ at one's place and filling ten's place with $8$ and hundred's place with $9$ gives us number $987$ with counts $1$ to total sum.

Total numbers : $28+15+6+1 = 50$

Answer (score 0):

---

the units digit can be 1or 3 or 5 so 3 ways(9 cannot be taken )
units digit when = 1       _ _ _1  ten's digit = 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
in this if ten's digit = 2  hundred's digit =  3,4,5,6,7,8,9..  -- 7 ways
in this if ten's digit = 3  hundred's digit =  4,5,6,7,8,9...     6 ways

so on upto ten's = 8 hundreds = 9 --1 way  i.e, nothing but  sum of first 7 terms  i.e, 28
similarly for unit's= 3  ten's digit = 4,5,6,7,8     hundred's digit =  ,5,6,7,8,9..  -- 5 ways

so on upto ten's = 8 hundreds = 9 --1 way  i.e, nothing but  sum of first 5 terms  i.e, 15

similarly for unit's = 5 the ways can be  6  total 28+15+6 = 49
one number remained is 987 with this it is 50 ways.

calculating this take more time can anyone reduce this or is there any formula for this type of ques...

Comment: 50 is correct, as shown by String's answer.  His hint made more explicit was that for a specific choice of $b$, there will be $\lfloor \frac{b}{2}\rfloor$ number of choices for $a$, and $9-b$ number of choices for $c$.  By multiplication principle then for a specific $b$, you have $(9-b)\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor$ number of choices.  Breaking this into cases for $b\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ and summing gives you [$\sum_{b=0}^9(9-b)\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+floor%28b%2F2%29*%289-b%29+from+b%3D0+to+9)=50